# Creating A Session timeout File Downloader PHP

Tags: php

Hi I'm not a developer yet! but I'm trying my best to learn and one the best community is StackOverflow which I'm getting addicted to.

So what I'm trying to do is!

I'm trying to create a [simple downloader](https://github.com/theshem/PHP-File-Downloader) like this.

But the problem is if someone has a direct link of this: download.php?ver=VERSION_NUMBER they can download file easily! I wanna put some restrictions that if someone get to a link and it should be just for him according to his session or ip address or token. if new user used that link again that link should not be working for other person!

I'm curious to know if this is possible! OR if it is possible then can you guys guide me a bit! so i can start searching for that.

Comment: The library you linked it mostly about resolving version numbers. How does that relate to your distribution control feature?

Comment: You need to provide them with more than a link. Try `download.php?ver=VERSION_NUMBER&key=DOWNLOAD_KEY`; where download key is a database field that you can check against (whether it's been accessed before, whether it's during a certain time range, whether it matches the current SESSIONID, etc.

Comment: @Halcyon i used that library as an example!

Comment: There are so many possible solutions. Lock by IP, session, single use tokens, expiring tokens you name it. They're all quite involved and stackoverflow is not really the place to ask someone to write code for you.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski They should get something like this http://example.com/downloads/file_name?st=6Elo75lzl9xYXSoNJVTFWg&e=1490545753 so i can keep my server safe from leechers and reduce high usage. i have seen many sites are using the same strategy.

Comment: @Halcyon Single use tokens that's what I'm looking for... for example this is a file link and <form>"Form input contains values"</form> example.com/download.php and when user redirect to download.php it should regenerate http://example.com/downloads/file_name?st=nsHy1sCsUXg4g9N8FbJGUA&e=1490546205 i can show you an example?

Comment: I would say that a single use token isn't the proper idea, but instead, tie it to data stored in the users session. But regardless, you'll need to add a database component to your site to track these tokens, when they were issued, if they've been used, if they've expired, etc.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski i found this one https://github.com/joshpangell/single-us and it's perfect! but if i have more then 100 files i can't keep creating array to initialize download file.